# Parse resume.json in multiple levels

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a json file, but I don't know how to loop root nodes that are arrays.

The resume.json - a [JSON-based standard for resumes](https://jsonresume.org/) - is here:

```
{
    "basics": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "label": "Programmer",
        "picture": "",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "phone": "(912) 555-4321",
        "website": "http://johndoe.com",
        "summary": "A summary of John Doe...",
        "location": {
            "address": "2712 Broadway St",
            "postalCode": "CA 94115",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "countryCode": "US",
            "region": "California"
        },
        "profiles": [{
            "network": "Twitter",
            "username": "john",
            "url": "http://twitter.com/john"
        }]
    },
    "work": [{
            "company": "Company",
            "position": "President",
            "website": "http://company.com",
            "startDate": "2013-01-01",
            "endDate": "2014-01-01",
            "summary": "Description...",
            "highlights": [
                "Started the company"
            ]
        },
        {
            "company": "Company",
            "position": "President",
            "website": "http://company.com",
            "startDate": "2013-01-01",
            "endDate": "2014-01-01",
            "summary": "Description...",
            "highlights": []
        }
    ],
    "volunteer": [{
        "organization": "Organization",
        "position": "Volunteer",
        "website": "http://organization.com/",
        "startDate": "2012-01-01",
        "endDate": "2013-01-01",
        "summary": "Description...",
        "highlights": [
            "Awarded 'Volunteer of the Month'"
        ]
    }],
    "education": [{
            "institution": "University",
            "area": "Software Development",
            "studyType": "Bachelor",
            "startDate": "2011-01-01",
            "endDate": "2013-01-01",
            "gpa": "4.0",
            "courses": [
                "DB1101 - Basic SQL"
            ]
        },
        {
            "institution": "University",
            "area": "Software Development 2",
            "studyType": "Master",
            "startDate": "2014-01-01",
            "endDate": "2016-01-01",
            "gpa": "6.0",
            "courses": []
        }
    ],
    "awards": [{
        "title": "Award",
        "date": "2014-11-01",
        "awarder": "Company",
        "summary": "There is no spoon."
    }],
    "publications": [{
        "name": "Publication",
        "publisher": "Company",
        "releaseDate": "2014-10-01",
        "website": "http://publication.com",
        "summary": "Description..."
    }],
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Web Development",
        "level": "Master",
        "keywords": [
            "HTML",
            "CSS",
            "Javascript"
        ]
    }],
    "languages": [{
        "name": "English",
        "level": "Native speaker"
    }],
    "interests": [{
            "name": "Wildlife",
            "keywords": [
                "Ferrets",
                "Unicorns"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Front-end Development",
            "level": "",
            "keywords": []
        }
    ],
    "references": [{
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "reference": "Reference..."
    }]
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$.getJSON('resume.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        var name = this.name;
        var label = this.label;
        console.log(name); // works
        console.log(label); // works
    });
});
```

But how can I retrieve the companies under the node "work"? Or the different institutions under "education"? How can I handle those arrays?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored in plain old Javascript arrays, as such you can just loop through them as needed. For example:

```
$.getJSON('resume.json', function(data) {
    // how can I retrieve the companies under the node "work"? 
    data.work.forEach(function(w) {
        console.log(w.company);
    })

    // Or the different institutions under "education"?
    data.education.forEach(function(e) {
        console.log(e.institution);
    })
});
```

```js
var data = {
  "basics": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "label": "Programmer",
    "picture": "",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(912) 555-4321",
    "website": "http://johndoe.com",
    "summary": "A summary of John Doe...",
    "location": {
      "address": "2712 Broadway St",
      "postalCode": "CA 94115",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "region": "California"
    },
    "profiles": [{
      "network": "Twitter",
      "username": "john",
      "url": "http://twitter.com/john"
    }]
  },
  "work": [{
    "company": "Company 1",
    "position": "President",
    "website": "http://company.com",
    "startDate": "2013-01-01",
    "endDate": "2014-01-01",
    "summary": "Description...",
    "highlights": [
      "Started the company"
    ]
  }, {
    "company": "Company 2",
    "position": "President",
    "website": "http://company.com",
    "startDate": "2013-01-01",
    "endDate": "2014-01-01",
    "summary": "Description...",
    "highlights": []
  }],
  "volunteer": [{
    "organization": "Organization",
    "position": "Volunteer",
    "website": "http://organization.com/",
    "startDate": "2012-01-01",
    "endDate": "2013-01-01",
    "summary": "Description...",
    "highlights": [
      "Awarded 'Volunteer of the Month'"
    ]
  }],
  "education": [{
    "institution": "University 1",
    "area": "Software Development",
    "studyType": "Bachelor",
    "startDate": "2011-01-01",
    "endDate": "2013-01-01",
    "gpa": "4.0",
    "courses": [
      "DB1101 - Basic SQL"
    ]
  }, {
    "institution": "University 2",
    "area": "Software Development 2",
    "studyType": "Master",
    "startDate": "2014-01-01",
    "endDate": "2016-01-01",
    "gpa": "6.0",
    "courses": []
  }],
  "awards": [{
    "title": "Award",
    "date": "2014-11-01",
    "awarder": "Company",
    "summary": "There is no spoon."
  }],
  "publications": [{
    "name": "Publication",
    "publisher": "Company",
    "releaseDate": "2014-10-01",
    "website": "http://publication.com",
    "summary": "Description..."
  }],
  "skills": [{
    "name": "Web Development",
    "level": "Master",
    "keywords": [
      "HTML",
      "CSS",
      "Javascript"
    ]
  }],
  "languages": [{
    "name": "English",
    "level": "Native speaker"
  }],
  "interests": [{
    "name": "Wildlife",
    "keywords": [
      "Ferrets",
      "Unicorns"
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Front-end Development",
    "level": "",
    "keywords": []
  }],
  "references": [{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "reference": "Reference..."
  }]
}

// how can I retrieve the companies under the node "work"? 
data.work.forEach(function(w) {
  console.log(w.company);
})

// Or the different institutions under "education"?
data.education.forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e.institution);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick approach for elements which has a finite nesting (meaning it's not infinite)

```
$.getJSON('resume.json', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      //you already have the key in 'i'
      if(i === "work") {
        //item is the actual value of "work"
        $.each(item, function(j, value) {
           console.log(value);
        })
      }
    });
});
```